# Java Listener for looped combo in Eclipse SWT

Tags: java, while-loop, combobox, swt, listener

I have a Java SWT GUI that I've built using Eclipse. I'm using a while loop to reference a text file. The while loop iterates through each line of the text file and builds a series of combo or text boxes for specific items on each line. Each line represents one visual column in the GUI and, depending on how many items I have in the text file, the GUI builds to the right. For simplicity's sake I am including just the code that I am trying to figure out.

For instance, assume I have three lines that create six combo boxes in the GUI (three columns by two rows). I would like a change on the top row in the second column to execute a Listener on the bottom row, also in the second column. However, right now the Listener loops through all of the combo's and makes a change to all three, not just the one I want. I can't figure out how to make this work. See the code below. I appreciate the help.

```
private void buildMultipleSatPulldowns() {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("MultipleSatellites.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line = null;
        String[] tempS;
        String constellation = null;
        String satellite = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            tempS = line.split("~");
            constellation = tempS[4];
            satellite = tempS[6];

            constNameCombo = new Combo(satellitesComposite2, SWT.NONE);
            constNameCombo.setToolTipText("Pulldown constellation name");
            constNameCombo.setBounds(startX + x2, 71, 125, 28);
            constNameCombo.setItems(constNameArray);
            constNameCombo.setText(constellation);
            constNameCombos.add(constNameCombo);

            constNameCombo.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() { // captures changed combo values
                public void modifyText(ModifyEvent arg0) {
                    setConstellationPD();
                }
            });

            sPullDown(constellation); // builds the satellite array for the constellation and populates each pulldown

            satNameCombo = new Combo(satellitesComposite2, SWT.NONE);
            satNameCombo.setToolTipText("Pulldown satellite name");
            satNameCombo.setBounds(startX + x2, 106, 125, 28);
            satNameCombo.setItems(satNameArray);
            satNameCombo.setText(satellite);
            satNameCombos.add(satNameCombo);

            startX = startX + nextX;

        }

        br.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setConstellationPD() {

    int constellations = 0;

    for (Combo constNameCombo : constNameCombos) {

        // What do I do here so that only the desired satNameCombo changes to reflect the desired pull down?

        setSatellitesPD(constellations, constNameCombo)

        constellations++;
    }

}

private void setSatellitesPD(int c, String cN) {
    int satellites = 0;

    for (Combo satNameCombo : satNameCombos) {
        if (c == satellites) {
            satNameCombo.setText(satNameCombos.get(satellites).toString());
            satNameCombo.removeAll();
            sPullDown(cN);
            satNameCombo.setText("select Satellite");
        }
        satellites++;
    }

}

private void sPullDown(String cName) {
    // sPullDown takes the constellation name and returns a String Array of all objects in the constellation. This code works correctly when called.
}
```

Comment: As a side note you should really look at using [Layouts](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm). Using setBounds will cause problems if you run the code on different platforms with different font sizes.

Comment: I'll check that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need a way to know which combo fired the event in order to affect some other components.

SWT events like `ModifyEvent` have the method `getSource()` which will return the object on which the event occurred.

Having that you just need to properly identify it; for example you could simply use `constNameCombos.indexOf(eventCombo)` to retrieve its index.

Or, more efficiently, you could attach some data to your combos with the method `setData` and retrieve it inside the event with `getData`, for example inside the loop:

```
// "i" would be the index of the combo
constNameCombo.setData("index", i);
i++;
```

and in the event:

```
Combo eventCombo = (Combo) arg0.getSource();
int index = eventCombo.getData("index");
```

With these information you should be able to identify the other components that you want to change.

Comment: Using what you gave me I was able to get it to work as desired. Thank you very much for the help.